# Create reducible matrices, perhaps with diag()

Tags: r, matrix

I have a few vectors that I would like to arrange into square matrices of the same dimensions for future multiplication. Some vectors are shorters than others so I would like to add zeros to the shorters ones so that all the resulting matrices are of the same dimension.

I tried to add 0 to the tail of the shorter vectors but I haven't been able to generate the reducible matrices that I want. Below are some pseudo data. Thank you for your time!

```
seq_a <- rep(1,4)
seq_b <- rep(1,3)

matA <- diag(seq_a)
matB <- matrix(c(diag(seq_b),0),nrow=4,ncol = 4)
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1
[4,]    0    0    0    0
Warning message:
In matrix(c(diag(seq_c), 0), nrow = 4, ncol = 4) :
  data length [10] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [4]
```

The desired matB should be

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is just a typo: you should first pad the vector, and then convert it to a diagonal matrix.

```
matB <- diag( c(seq_b,0) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!